# How can I plot a Quarter graph in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I wanna to plot a graph as the below:

[image]

And this one:

[image]

I was doing something like this:

```
cc=hsv(ns);
hold on;
for nk=1:ns
    figure(4); hold on;
    h=plot(M1(nk,:),':','color',cc(nk,:));
    set(h,'linewidth',2)
end
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Just plot the lines using `plot` and add the text using `text`. What's the problem?

Comment: @David How How I can make it appear Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4?

Comment: With the `text` function, http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html

Comment: Please show us your code up to now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first plot you just need to use `plot` and `text` plus some tweaking. If you want the legend in two columns, have a look at [`columnlegend`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27389-columnlegend) in the *Matlab File Exchange*.

```
% generate some data
days  = (1:250);
M1 = (days'*[0.06,-0.03,0.02,-0.04,0.05,-0.05,0.01])';
M1 = M1 + 0.5*randn(size(M1));
years  = 2002+(1:size(M1,1));

ns = size(M1,1);

% prepare plot
figure(4); hold on;
cc = hsv(ns);

% plot all prices
for nk = 1:ns
    ph = plot(days,M1(nk,:),'Color',cc(nk,:));
    set(ph,'LineWidth',2);
end

% plot texts
for i = 1:4  
    h = text(250/8+(i-1)*250/4,18,['Q',num2str(i)]);
    set(h,'FontSize',13,'HorizontalAlignment','center');
end

% plot vertical lines and the horizontal line
plot([250,250]'*(0:4)/4,[-21,21],'k-.');
plot([-10,250+10],[0,0],'k-.');

% set limits
set(gca,'XLim',[-10,250+10]);
set(gca,'YLim',[-21,21]);

% set labels and legend
xlabel('Day of Trading');
ylabel('Normalized Price');
lh = legend(cellstr(num2str(years')),'Location','SouthWest');
set(lh,'FontSize',8);

% tweak appearance
set(gca,'YTick',-20:10:20);
set(gca,'FontSize',13);
set(gca,'GridLineStyle',':');
grid on;
box on;
```

*This is the result:*

[image: result1]

---

The second plot is very similar to the first one. For the confidence interval you can use `fill`. Because the entries in the legend have a different order as the order of plotting them, we store the handles and give it as the first argument to `legend`.

```
% generate some data
rng(2);
days = (1:250);
realised_Q1 = (1:62)*0.04+0.5*randn(1,62);
realised_Q234 = realised_Q1(end)+(1:189)*0.03+0.5*randn(1,189);
forecast_Q234 = realised_Q1(end)-3*sin((1:189)/40);
confidence_up = forecast_Q234+(1-exp(-(0:188)/10));
confidence_down = forecast_Q234-(1-exp(-(0:188)/10));

% prepare plot
figure; hold on;
ph = zeros(4,1);

% plot confidence interval
ph(4) = fill([days(62:250),fliplr(days(62:250))],...
             [confidence_up,fliplr(confidence_down)],...
             [0.85,0.85,1],'EdgeColor','none');

% plot realized Q1
ph(1) = plot(days(1:62),realised_Q1,'r','LineWidth',2);

% plot realized Q2 Q3 Q4 and forecast Q2 Q3 Q4
ph(2) = plot(days(62:250),realised_Q234,'k','LineWidth',2);
ph(3) = plot(days(62:250),forecast_Q234,'b','LineWidth',2);

% plot texts
for i = 1:4  
    h = text(250/8+(i-1)*250/4,13,['Q',num2str(i)]);
    set(h,'FontSize',13,'HorizontalAlignment','center');
end

% plot vertical lines and the horizontal line
plot([250,250]'*(0:4)/4,[-21,21],'k-.');
plot([-10,250+10],[0,0],'k-.');

% set limits
set(gca,'XLim',[-10,250+10]);
set(gca,'YLim',[-6,16]);

% set labels and legend
xlabel('Day of Trading');
ylabel('Normalized Price');
lh = legend(ph,'Realized Q1 (2011)','Realized Q2 Q3 Q4 (2011)',...
           'Forecast Q2 Q3 Q4 (2011)','Confidence',...
           'Location','SouthWest');
set(lh,'FontSize',8);

% tweak appearance
set(gca,'YTick',-5:5:15);
set(gca,'FontSize',13);
set(gca,'GridLineStyle',':');
grid on;
box on;
```

*This is the result:*
[image: result2]